# Why does the compiler not generate default constructor if I delete the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code raises an error "No matching constructor for initialization of 'A'". Why does the default constructor cannot apply to it? I am using C++ 17.

```
class A {
public:
    A(const A& a) = delete;
    static void test() {
        A a; // raises an error
    }
};
```

I tried to add a default constructor explicitly, it works.

Answer (score 9):

`A` gets no default constructor generated by the compiler because there is a user declared constructor.

If you want the compiler generated definition of default constructor but no copy constructor then that is:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A& a) = delete;
    static void test() {
        A a; // calls A::A()
    }
};
```

Consider that `=delete` and `=default` are rather recent additions to c++, so in the past declaring some constructor was the way to prevent the compiler to generate the default constructor (while now you can make it explicit via `A() = delete;`). If `=delete` was available from the beginning things would maybe be different, or maybe not. No default constructor is generated by the compiler when you declare a constructor. `A(const A& a) = delete;` is declaring a constructor, even if it is deleted.

Comment: I am curious about why would C++ make it like this, cause deleting a constructor counts as a constructor declaration seems make no sense. Does C++ standard specify this behaviour?

Comment: @scengka "counts as a constructor declaration seems make no sense." why not? You *declare* the constructor to be deleted.

Comment: @scengka yes this is specified in the c++ standard. You can also read about it here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor and here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions